# facebook error : sorry, something went wrong when trying to signin android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating facebook login inside my application. I have placed all the required code inside my fragment class. I have also registered my app in the facebook developer console. and placed fb_app_id inside my string.xml. Whenever I am hitting the facebook log in button it redirects me to Screen on the browser which says **"Sorry, Something went wrong, We are working on it"**

**LogCat Message**:

> E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33,
>   errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get
>   request. Object with ID 'fb_app_id' does not exist, cannot be
>   loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
>   Please read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}

Here is what I have done so far:

My HomeFragment code:

**Inside onCreateView function**:

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

                if (currentAccessToken == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User logged out successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton.setFragment(this);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"user_photos", "email",
                "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken"}));
        // If you are using in a fragment, call loginButton.setFragment(this);

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                getProfileData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
```

**After this, I have created GetProfileData function and onActivityResult callback :**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void getProfileData() {
        try {
            accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                            try {
                                String name = object.getString("name");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name" + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields",
                    "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Inside my app/gradle file**:

> implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.0'

**Here is the code under application tag in my Manifest file**:

> ```
>     <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
>         android:configChanges=
>             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" />
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
>         android:exported="true">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>             <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

Please let me know if I am missing something. I have added key hash to developer console and followed each step as mentioned in the official facebook developer site i.e https://developers.facebook.com/apps/559151138175777/fb-login/quickstart/.

Comment: @04FS, Thanks for your reply, Can you please elaborate your answer that which permissions are non-existing?.

Comment: `AccessToken` is not a permission.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you man